# Implementing a simple achievement system for dotnet mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on creating a banking application for a school project that uses ASP.net MVC 4. As part of the application we have a set of achievements for the user. When the User completes an achievement, say "Create a Savings Account" they should be rewarded by unlocking the achievement and sending a notification. Here's the Achievement Class:

```
    public class Achievement
    {
        public string UserID { get; set; }

        public AchievementType AchType { get; set; }

        public bool Completed { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int CountToUnlock { get; set; }
    }

    public enum AchievementType
    {
        CREATE_SAVINGS_ACCOUNT, CREATE_GOAL, COMPLETE_GOAL, ACCOUNT_5K,
        ACCOUNT_10K, UPDATE_GOAL, ADD_TRANSACTION, SAVE_1K_TOTAL
    };
```

The part I'm struggling with is how to make sure that every user has the same set of achievements and where to trigger those achievements. Whether they should be in an AchievementController or someplace else.

Answer (score 0):

My initial reaction is that you should have a Customer class, which contains a List of that customer's achievements.

Where you trigger the adding of these achievements, depends upon where the logic lives that determines when they've reached one of the goals.  For your school project, are you going to rig up a page to simulate this?

Some pseudo to get you started:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Achievement> Achievements { get; set; }

    public bool AddAchievement(Achievement newAchievement)
    {
        // Check to ensure customer doesn't already have the new achievement

        // Persist to the database

        // Add to local collection
        Achievements.Add(newAchievement);

        // Send email to customer

        // Anything else

        // Return
        return true;
    }
}
```

Suggestion:  Your enum's options should be ProperCase, and put one item on each line.  Good to make them adequately descriptive too.

```
public enum AchievementType
{
    CreatedSavingsAccount,
    CreatedGoal,
    CompletedGoal,
    AccountBalance5000,
    // [...]
}
```